# USB Dualshock 3 controller on Windows 8.1 (Code 43)

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, cable, game-controller, peripherals

I have a Sony Dualshock 3 controller that I used to use a lot on Windows 7. Windows 8.1 seems to be having some trouble with it. I get 'error code 43.' I use the driver by Scarlet.Crush: http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller

I've already confirmed that the controller works fine on the PlayStation via wireless, so I don't see how it could be a hardware problem. I am using a different wire than before, but I don't think that that could be the problem since the computer is clearly finding *something*.

Here is a screenshot showing some relevant information:

[image]

**Update:** I tried the old USB cable. The error goes away! The controller gets detected.

The only problem now is that there is something either wrong with the cable or the controller's micro-USB port. It gets detected then dropped, detected again, dropped again, and so on. The other cable didn't have this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you should try another cable if that doesn't work then try it on another pc if it works the. It's possible the driver doesn't support Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

windows asks your controller what kind of device it is and the device doesnt answer the question. it often is about cable or connection.